# Where does Windows 10 keep the welcome images?

Tags: windows-10, windows-spotlight

After installation, and for a few days, Windows 10 starts by asking you if you like a series of images that appear when you start the computer, then, based on your opinion, a selection of these images keep "welcoming" you. I'd like to know where these images are saved (and how, if it's a database or a change of format-extension).

I might want some of them, I might want to add a few of my own.

Does anybody know the path to these images (or database)? Is there documentation or options in Windows 10 to treat them?

Comment: You're quite right :). I think they only appear if you select "Yes, I want to contribute..." to one of those feedback programs. But I do like the pictures (hope they don't use 'em against me).

Comment: Oh my, I just got a down arrow. Is this that bad a question?

Comment: Second down arrow! I better erase this question or end with no reputation!!! Help me Meta!

Comment: (Or) Can someone tell me why I get down arrows for this?

Comment: IMHO the question is ok. But it might be that the answer is already available on Google and you just didn't do much research.

Comment: I did, a little. But, the way I see it, it was Anant's answer that helped me name things, and just then I could find the answer on google. Perhaps I did lack a little research in my own machine, he he. 
Yes, you're right, I take my down arrows with dignity.

Comment: @Ignorante I think it is a great question. I just had the same question, and your answer was great. Have an upvote!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the location of lock screen images on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126403/what-is-the-location-of-lock-screen-images-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Anant Milk now I know this is called the Lock Screen. Knowing that, I found the answer in google: 
http://www.tenforums.com/customization/5428-windows-spotlight-lock-screen-image-location.html

The path to the images in Lock Screen (and some others used by the system) is

```
C:\Users\{your name}\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txy‌​ewy\LocalState\Assets
```

Rename extensions to jpg and you can get them.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10/11, there is a difference between the desktop background wallpapers installed as part of the Windows theme, and the Windows Spotlight wallpaper which (if enabled) appears on the lockscreen. They can be found here:

| Item | Online repository | Local dir |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Theme wallpapers | [Microsoft Support Windows Wallpapers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wallpapers-5cfa0cc7-b75a-165a-467b-c95abaf5dc2a#WindowsVersion=Windows_10) | `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` |
| Windows Spotlight | [windows10spotlight.com](https://windows10spotlight.com) | `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets` |