# Windows Spotlight Source and Save locations?

Tags: windows-10, windows-spotlight

Where are the images from [Windows Spotlight](http://www.winbeta.org/news/microsoft-announces-windows-spotlight-new-lockscreen-experience-windows-10) coming from?  Where are they being saved on my system?  Is there any way for me to point this at my own source of images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pictures are located at:

> C:\Users{your_name}\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets

And they will look like this:
[image]

Renaming these to .JPG will reveal it as a picture but I am not sure there is a way to generate the names. So the only idea I have is to note the existing names and rename your own pictures to match them...

Answer (score 1):

Ditto @TomEus

Here is a script to save them to a sub-folder in your local Pictures folder.  Also works for [windows-11](/questions/tagged/windows-11) through build 22631.2428.

```
Get-ChildItem $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets |
ForEach-Object ($file) {
    if ((Test-Path -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Pictures\Windows Spotlight\$($_.Name).jpg") -eq $false) {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$env:USERPROFILE\Pictures\Windows Spotlight\$($_.Name).jpg" #-WhatIf
        }
    }
Start-Process explorer -ArgumentList "$env:USERPROFILE\Pictures\Windows Spotlight"
```