# Windows 10 Spotlight – how do I know which photos I marked as "I am a fan"?

Tags: windows-10, photos, windows-spotlight

I have been clicking the "I am a fan" option (from "Like what you see?" dropdown) on photographs of the pre-login-screen in Windows 10 ([Windows Spotlight](https://superuser.com/a/1112013/613335)) for a few months now.

Is there a way to know which photos I have previously marked as "I am a fan"/"not a fan"?

### EDIT:

These photos can be found in the hard drive by going to (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>):

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
```

[This answer explains how to get the details of the photograph (through EXIF, XMP, etc.)](https://superuser.com/a/1031914/613335), thanks Moab for the URL.

Comment: Its called windows spotlight, it stores the ones you like and deletes the ones you don't...they are stored in C:\Users\{your name}\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets

Comment: Copy them into another folder and rename the file extensions to .jpg to see them.

Comment: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-save-all-windows-spotlight-lockscreen-images

Comment: Possible Duplicate...http://superuser.com/questions/1011968/how-do-i-get-more-information-about-windows-spotlight-images

Comment: @Moab thanks for letting me know where they are stored, but I'm asking which ones I marked as "I'm a fan"/"Not a fan" from the Windows Spotlight dropdown. I'll rephrase the title of my question in order to be more perceptible.

Comment: They are not marked, ones that are selected as "not a fan" are deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there a way to know which photos I have previously marked as "I am a fan"/"not a fan"?"

No, when you select "not a fan" they are deleted from the spotlight folder. Ones you mark as "I am a fan" are left in the spotlight folder.

If you want to keep all the images always select "I am a Fan"

This is the folder they are stored in:

> %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets

Comment: Oh, thanks again Moab. I was kind of hoping to undo some of those I marked as "not a fan" (and actually check those I didn't like before). I'll use that [SpotBright](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/spotbright/9nblggh5km22) app they have to get them all then.