# Can't find specific Windows 10 Spotlight Lock-Screen Image

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, windows-spotlight

I'm looking for following Windows 10 Spotlight Lock-screen Image as a File:

[image: Windows Lock-screen Image]

So far i tried:

- Grabbing it from the `AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\` Folder. But there the given picture wasn't found.
- Find it on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18827/places-landscapes-wallpaper . A lot of beautiful pictures, but not this one.

Any other suggestions where i can look for it?

Comment: The ones who are interested in the geographic location of this image may search it as "Lake Quill"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to track it down using Google images:
https://richardtech.net/2015/07/windows-10-wallpapers/

Answer (score 1):

[Other answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1011968/how-do-i-get-more-information-about-windows-spotlight-images?rq=1) in the past have directed people to the [SpotBright](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/spotbright/9nblggh5km22) app from the Windows Store. From there you should be able to download all Spotlight images and quickly scan through them to find this one.

I share your frustration, though - I've looked in my own folder at the path you gave a few times before, and it always seems like new images are appearing and old ones are disappearing.