# Where to read the full story of the Windows 10 spotlight image

Tags: windows-10, windows-spotlight

Windows 10 spotlight image is teasing me with an interesting story:

[image]

But when I click it, [a link](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%C3%A4gerisee+switzerland&filters=IsConversation:%22True%22+BTWLKey:%22AgeriseeSwitzerland%22+BTWLType:%22Trivia%22&FORM=EMSDS0) opens in Microsoft Edge, which contains the image, but the story is not finished:

[image]

The text which started the story ("Long ago, something happened on the shores of this lovely lake that would help found one of the world's ...") is not present anywhere on the page , neither it's present when I click those links there.

### How do I find the completion of the story of the Spotlight image?

(I mean, completion of the very text which of which I just see first few sentences on the locked screen, marked by the red ellipse above.)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://superuser.com/questions/1011968/how-do-i-get-more-information-about-windows-spotlight-images

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the link. Well, it doesn't. I am able to download the full res image, find out the location etc., but I am asking about the **completion of the very text which of which I just see first few sentences on the locked screen.**

Comment: You might find the text or some part of it inside the metadata of the image, as explained in my link.

Comment: @harrymc are you able to get the completion of the text of *your* spotlight image?

Answer (score 0):

The same screenshot reads, "Long ago, something happened on the shores of this lovely lake that would help found one of the world's ... most beautiful and prosperous countries."